# C# Basic Optimisation Techniques

Tags: c#, class, optimization, methods, parameters

I have two questions about making code faster, and exactly how much certain things will slow down my program.

First off, method parameters. Lets say I have a program which has a base class called Account, and then I create many instances of this class Account. In the class, it has a method called Example, with heaps of method parameters. Is it slow to do this? Is hard coding the stuff faster, if so how much? Example:

```
public class Example
{
    public void DoSomething(string One, string Two, string Three, string Four, string Five, string Six, string Seven, string Eight, string Nine, string Ten, string Eleven)
    {
    // make a WebRequest using these parameters.
    }

}
```

Secondly, is it bad to have a class with only one member inside of it, a instance of a base class, like Example (above). For example:

```
static class ExampleOne
{
    public static Example example = new Example();
}
```

And then using it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ExampleOne.example.DoSomething(parameters);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could pass references of parameters - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Comment: Hardcoding the parameters is *barely* faster, certainly you will not be able to tell any difference, but it's the wrong question to ask. Do you need configurability or not? All the "is it slow?/how much?" questions have the same answer: **measure it**. The class member example looks quite bad.

Comment: When it comes to performance, unless there's O(n) vs O(1) (or something similar), it's mostly guesses which is actually faster and/or difference is so small it does not even matter. To get actual results, profile code.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I guess the difference is so tiny I really don't need to worry. Thanks again.

Comment: @NSmeef A reference to `string` and a `string` are *exactly* the same size in C# and passing stuff by reference only incurs an additional indirection thereby making the program slower..

Comment: The first rule of optimization is: "Don't." Make the program *work*. Then determine if it's fast enough. If it's not fast enough, then use a profiler to determine where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// make a WebRequest using these parameters.
```

You are doing this fundamentally wrong.  Network latency ensures that this method is going to take many milliseconds to execute.  Anything you could gain from tinkering with the way you call this method, at best measured at a handful of *nanoseconds*, is never going to be observable.

Your started wrong, you didn't use a profiler to find what *needed* to be optimized.

Comment: So the way I use the code, with the classes and methods, will only really slow my program down by nanoseconds?

Comment: @user2764359: That's exactly what he's saying.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your second question:

It depends on what you want to accomplish, but I think you should either use a static method or implement the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern instead.